# Docker cloud submodule authentication

Tags: docker, docker-cloud

I have a program that i want to autobuild through docker cloud but it has a submodule that it pulls aswell. I can build the image on my own machine but it always fail when I try to build.

```
Building in Docker Cloud's infrastructure...
Cloning into '.'...
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '104.192.143.3' to the list of known hosts.
Submodule 'joule-config' (git@hannanrhodes@bitbucket.org/jouleai/joule-service.git) registered for path 'joule-config'
fatal: repository 'git@hannanrhodes@bitbucket.org/jouleai/joule-service.git' does not exist
Clone of 'git@hannanrhodes@bitbucket.org/jouleai/joule-service.git' into submodule path 'joule-config' failed
please ensure the correct public key is added to the list of trusted keys for this repository and the remote branch exists. (1)
ERROR: Build failed: please ensure the correct public key is added to the list of trusted keys for this repository and the remote branch exists. (1)
ERROR: Build failed with exit code 2
ERROR: Build in 'master:/joule-service' (0123da2c) failed in 0:01:32
```